# iOS Swift : UITableView KeyPad overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

I have an `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. When I start searching in `UITableView` , some rows are displayed under keyboard.
What should I do so all of them are visible ? Need to set any layoutIfNeeded() or something ?
Thanks in advance and have a great day !

Comment: you can change the hight of table view by its bottom constraint or which is preferable for your as per desing. Create IBOutlet of Bottom constraint of your tableview, and in keyBoardWillShow and hide methods just change the constaint.constant value accordingly, you will get the height of keybord in this methods, don't forgot to send layOutIfNeeded message to your tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a `UITableViewController` directly then this would be the preferred approach as it does automatic keyboard avoidance.

If this isn't possible you will have to implement it yourself. Something like this should work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue().size
    let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

    var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    } else {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.width, 0.0)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(rate.doubleValue) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }

    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.editingIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

    UIView.animateWithDuration(rate.doubleValue) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
}
```

Ported by myself from the original Objective-C code by [Brandon King](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/keyboard-content-offset/):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
    CGSize keyboardSize = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSNumber *rate = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.height), 0.0);
    } else {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize.width), 0.0);
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:rate.floatValue animations:^{
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.editingIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSNumber *rate = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:rate.floatValue animations:^{
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Made it work using `NSNotificationCenter` for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` . Thank you !

Comment: error: Property 'editingIndexPath' not found on object of type 'ViewController. Any solution for this

Comment: @G.Abhisek You will have to track this yourself with the `UITableViewDelegate` methods `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Original by Steve Wilford - converted to Swift 3 by me

```
var myIndexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
  }

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size
    let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

    var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation) {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    } else {
        contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.width, 0.0)
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }

    tableView.scrollToRow(at: myIndexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification){
    let rate = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

    UIView.animate(withDuration: rate.doubleValue) {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```